# Getting nullpointer exception for 2nd test case working fine for login

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

Driver set to null for 2nd test case, working fine for login.

Driver class:

```
public class Driver {

private static WebDriver driver;;

/**
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static synchronized WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {

    if (null == driver) {
        Properties properties = Utility.getproperties(Constant.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH);
        String browser = properties.getProperty(Constant.BROWSER);
        String url = properties.getProperty(Constant.URL);
        switch (browser) {
        case Constant.CHROME:
        //  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version(Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION).setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
             System.out.println(WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getVersions());
            break;
        case Constant.IE:
            WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
            //WebDriverManager.iedriver().version(Constant.IE_DRIVER_VERSION).setup();
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            break;
        case Constant.FIREFOX:
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            //WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().version(Constant.FIREFOX_DRIVER_VERSION).setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println(Message.SUITABLE_DRIVER_NOT_FOUND);
            break;

        }
        if (null != driver) {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

    }

    return driver;

}

@AfterMethod
public void quitDriver() {
    if (null != driver) {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
}
```

Login page:

```
public class LoginPage {

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = PageUtility.OKTA_SIGNIN_USERNAME_ID)
@CacheLookup
public WebElement userNameTextField;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = PageUtility.SIGNIN_PASSWORD_ID)
@CacheLookup
public WebElement passwordTextField;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = PageUtility.SIGNIN_SUBMIT_ID)
@CacheLookup
public WebElement signInButton;
}
```

LoginBusiness:

```
public class LoginBusiness extends LoginPage {

public LoginBusiness(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);

}
public void loginToApplication() throws IOException {
    userNameTextField.clear();
    Properties properties=Utility.getproperties(Constant.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH);
    String username=properties.getProperty(Constant.USERNAME);
    userNameTextField.sendKeys(username);
    String password=properties.getProperty(Constant.PASSWORD);
    passwordTextField.clear();
    passwordTextField.sendKeys(password);
    signInButton.click();
    }   
}
```

LoginTest:

```
public class LoginTest extends LoginBusiness {

public LoginBusiness loginBusiness;
public static WebDriver driver;

public LoginTest() throws Exception {
    super(driver);
    loginBusiness = PageFactory.initElements(Driver.getDriver(), LoginBusiness.class);
}

@Test
public void loginToGmsrApplication() throws IOException {



    loginBusiness.loginToApplication();



}
```

Terms&condpage:

```
public class TermsAndConditionsPage {

private static WebDriver driver;

public TermsAndConditionsPage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);


}

@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = PageUtility.ACCEPT_BUTTON_XPATH)
@CacheLookup
public WebElement acceptButton;

}
```

Terms&condibusines:

```
public class TermsAndConditionsBusiness extends TermsAndConditionsPage {

private static WebDriver driver;

public TermsAndConditionsBusiness(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);

}

public void clickToAcceptbutton() {

    Assert.assertEquals("Wrong message", "Accept", acceptButton.getText());
    acceptButton.click();


}
}
```

Terms&condtc:

```
public class TermsAndConditionsTest extends TermsAndConditionsBusiness{

public TermsAndConditionsBusiness termsAndConditionsBusiness;

public static WebDriver driver;
public TermsAndConditionsTest() throws Exception {

    super(driver);


    termsAndConditionsBusiness = PageFactory.initElements(Driver.getDriver(),TermsAndConditionsBusiness.class);
}

@Test
public void acceptTermsAndConditions() throws Exception {


    termsAndConditionsBusiness.clickToAcceptbutton();

}

}
```

Comment: At a guess, it's because you have an @AfterMethod that completely destroys the driver object. I'd suggest debugging and stepping through your code to find out exactly what is happening and working from there.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the `private static WebDriver driver` in `TermsAndConditions` page object, also the static is unnecessary:

```
private WebDriver driver;

public TermsAndConditionsBusiness(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    this.driver = driver;
}
```

Comment: why do we need to inialize Webdriver on every page

Comment: no webdriver initialized for login page as well only its defined in Driver class

Comment: To use `WebDriver` objects in other classes you need to pass instance to it. That is why you need to set it in the constructor via `this.driver = driver`. This way all your page object classes use the same driver object. Now I am not 100% sure if that is the cause of NullPointer here, as you did not provide the log output. Attaching the logs can help with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as [Moro](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/39306/moro) suggested you are not using the correct driver instance in term and condition.
Below pointers can help:

1. remove `public static WebDriver driver;` from all page, business and testcase classes as you are getting it in constructor there is no need for new instance in each class
2. In test case class use `super(Driver.getDriver())` in constructor instead `super(driver)`
3. Last move your @afterMethod to testcase class from Driver class. As it won't be running in driver class.